# MCMC Metropolis-Hastings with random matrices

Tags: normal-distribution, matrix, metropolis-hastings

I would like to approximate the solution to the following regression model with MCMC methods, as it can the be the core for solving more complex bayesian problems later on.

$$ U = Y - ZB $$

$$ U \ \sim \ \mathcal{MN}_{T \times K} (0,I,\Sigma) $$

I guess I would need to sample the distribution of the coefficient matrix $B$ (that is $12 \times K$) and $\Sigma$ which should be a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix of size $K \times K$. $Z$ is $T \times 12$ and $Y$ and $U$ are both $T \times K$.

$K = 4$ in this problem and also $T = 60$.

So far, I have tried to tailor the the random walk version of the Metropolis algorithm to my problem. I have come up with the following:

a) Set some initial values that could be for example the $OLS$ or $ML$ estimates

$$ C_0 = \begin{bmatrix}
    B_0 \\
    \Sigma_0
\end{bmatrix} $$

b) Generate a new candidate value from this equation

$$ C^* = C_{t-1} + E $$

$$ E \ \sim \ \mathcal{MN}_{(T+K) \times K} (0,I,I) $$

c) Define the probability of $C$ as the likelihood

$$ P(C_t) = (2 \pi)^{T/2} |\Sigma|^{T/2} \exp{(-0.5 \ \text{tr}[\Sigma^{-1} (Y - ZB)' (Y - ZB) ])} $$

d) Calculate the acceptance probability according to

$$ \alpha = \min \{ 1, \frac{P(C^*)}{P(C_{t-1})} \}$$

e) Draw a random number $u$ from a $Uniform(0,1)$ distribution

f) If $u < \alpha$, then set $C_t = C^*$, otherwise $C_t = C_{t-1}$

g) Repeat the previous steps the desired amount of MCMC iterations

Did I correctly specified the algorithm? Could anyone help me with that? I tried the above with 10.000, 100.000 and 1 million iterations but it didn't converge to anything.

I'm not sure if I am getting the theory wrong of if it's just a matter of the MCMC size being to short to sample such a plethora of parameters.

Any alternate strategy or reference is appreciated.

See below the MATLAB code used:

```
SV = vertcat(Bh,Sigmah);

burnin = 2.5*10^3;
mcmcreps = 10^4;
mcmcsize = burnin + mcmcreps;
mcmc = zeros(size(Bh,1)+K,size(Bh,2),mcmcsize);
mcmc(:,:,1) = SV;

rng default

for i=1:mcmcsize-1
    X_CN = mcmc(:,:,i) + randn(size(Bh,1)+K,size(Bh,2));
    l_new = mnlvar(X_CN(1:size(Bh,1),:),X_CN(size(Bh,1)+1:end,:),K,T,Y,Z);
    l_old = mnlvar(mcmc(1:size(Bh,1),:,i),mcmc(size(Bh,1)+1:end,:,i),K,T,Y,Z);
    ACCEPT = min(1,l_new/l_old);
    if rand < ACCEPT
        mcmc(:,:,i+1) = X_CN;
    else
        mcmc(:,:,i+1) = mcmc(:,:,i);
    end
end

Bh_median = median(mcmc,3);

function l = mnlvar(B,V,K,T,Y,Z)
l = (2*pi)^(-K*T/2)*det(V)^(T/2)*exp((-1/2)*trace(V\((Y-Z*B)'*(Y-Z*B))));
end
```

Comment: What are you asking for in response?

Comment: I would like to know If it's possible to apply Metropolis Hastings to sample a matrix with the steps above in the question (and if it's computationally possible) or if I should try another method.

Comment: (A confirmation if what I am doing is supposed to work or not, because so far it hasnt)